# How Generate Access Token from Client Id and Secret Id in android or java

Tags: java, android

i want to generate access token from secret id and client id in android ,  Please help me ?
Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to use any server (backend service), 
i am assuming that you are using nodeJs server on back-end.

> Send **secret id** to node js server where it checks in db that if the user
>   already exists then generate **jwt token** in return ,else create a new
>   user by its secret id and return a **jwt token** and save this token on client
>   side to authenticate every request in headers.

Comment: i want generate it in my app , no server

Comment: auth-tokens are generated on server

Comment: from where did you get secret id ?

Comment: yeah, i have it